# Protecting PHP against MySQL injections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I'm a total PHP noob, and while I read up on MySQL injections and protecting my script, I thought I would post what I have so far here.

Below is my current (working, yet bad practice) code. Can someone offer up my weak spots, and what I can do to fix?

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php'; //database information

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password)
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
  or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql="INSERT INTO users (email)
VALUES ('$email')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
header('Location: ../thankyou.php');
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Warning
This extension ( mysql_query ) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include: mysqli_query()
PDO::query() http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're in your own words a noob there's no time like the present to pick up some good habits :)

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sql="INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES ('$email')";
```

is a textbook example of an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability, and this code will [bite you](http://xkcd.com/327/) sooner or later.  The reason is that you trust the variable you receive, and hand it over to the SQL engine.  Just imagine what happens if someone enters

`'); drop table users; --`

as their email address...

Instead of devising all kinds of sophisticated schemes to clean up the input, there's one ironclad technique that makes your code immune against injection attacks: prepared statements.  As you should not start developing the deprecated mysql_ calls offered by php, you should switch to PDO or mysqli_.  I would suggest PDO, which supports prepared statements.  More about prepared statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).  Using PDO and prepared statments, your sample will look like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (:email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

You will have future proof code that's ready to be used with other database systems than MySQL and that's immune to injection attacks.